# How to copy only files(not directories) using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

The directory structure is:

```
  Images
    -Folder1
      -image1.jpg
      -image2.jpg
    -Folder2
      -image3.jpg
      -image4.png 
    -Folder3
      -image6.png
      -image7.jpg 
    -Folder4
```

I want to copy all images(i.e *.jpg, *.png) files only (not the folders) into the parent directory("Images").

I have tried using "robocopy" as follows:

```
robocopy /np ..\..\Exam\Images ..\..\Exam\Images *.jpg *.png /S
```

Here all files as well as folders are copied :(. But I need only files to be copied. How to do this?

Many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this on the command line:

```
for /r "Images" %i in (*.jpg *.png) do copy "%~fi" "my\target folder"
```

For a bach script the `%`  must be doubled `%%`.

Comment: Thank you a lot :). It worked. I just changed it to my specific requirement as follows:

for /r ..\..\Exam\Images %%f in (*.jpg,*.png) do copy %%f ..\..\Exam\Images

Comment: You use this without wildcards `*`  ?

Comment: Opps!. No, I used the wild card(*) i.e *.jpg, *.png in this case.  Thank you for pointing this.

Answer (score 1):

I think COPY or XCOPY is best used for files while I prefer Robocopy when dealing with folders.

Using the posted example try: (adjust paths to suit your needs.

```
    @Echo off
    For /f %%b In ('Dir C:\Exam\Images /b /s /a:d') Do (
       Robocopy %%b C:\Exam\Images *.jpg *.png /xx /np
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy only has the /XD switch to exclude directories but it excludes the whole directory. I'd use a batch file to do it instead.

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%a in ('dir *.jpg *.png /b /s /a-d') do (
   copy %%a PathToImagesFolder
)
```

Answer (score 0):

an easier way of doing this might be

for /r %%p in (*.png, *.jpg) do copy %%p destinationFolder.

Answer (score 0):

there is an easy to use program called Drop-It if this is a repetitive task then you can use this to sort|move|copy the files to a single directory. hope this helps